# How do I indent ALL lines of a paragraph so that it looks like a blockquote?

Tags: indentation, quoting

I understand that there is a `\quote` (correct me if I'm wrong) macro to do this; but I'm using this for something else (not prose). I also want it to obey the right margin. My minimal working example below requires me to guess the `\parbox` width, which is not a best practice. See the line with the `\newcommand{\myquote}...`

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\myquote}[1]{\vskip6pt\noindent\hangindent=5em\hangafter=0\parbox{4in}{#1}\vskip6pt}

\begin{document}

The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

\myquote{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

$E=mc^2$ by Einstein

\end{document}
```

Comment: Quick hack {`\leftskip30pt\noindent` your text............. (Just have a blank line at the end or a `\par`}

Comment: See also [indentation - Indenting a whole paragraph - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35933/indenting-a-whole-paragraph)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I've always found it rather counter-intuitive that the various quote environments are implemented via the generic `list` environment (IIRC, the `adjustwidth` from memoir is also implemented that way). Recently, I had trouble combining `adjustwidth` with `\obeylines` (and some other stuff), giving me a "missing `\item`" error. Then I found `\leftskip` and `\rightskip` in the TeXbook. I think this is what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{blockquote}{%
  \par%
  \medskip
  \leftskip=4em\rightskip=2em%
  \noindent\ignorespaces}{%
  \par\medskip}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{blockquote}
  \lipsum[2]

  \lipsum[3]
\end{blockquote}

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

If you want the first paragraph of the quote indented, just remove the `\noindent`. If you don't want the first paragraph after the quote to be indented, insert `\aftergroup\@afterindentfalse\aftergroup\@afterheading` after the last `\medskip`, and put a `\makeatletter` / `\makeatother` pair before/after the `\newenvironment`.

Comment: <note on leftskip drawback> https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/370816/indent-a-whole-section-all-lines-but-the-first#comment915801_370819

Answer (score 8):

Internally, `quote` is defined using the `list` environment, you can define your own by copying and modifying its original definition

```
\newenvironment{myquote}{%
   \list{}{\rightmargin\leftmargin}\item\relax
   % and maybe do more stuff
}{\endlist}
```

Comment: You have been a little bit faster.

Answer (score 5):

Old question, but I thought I'd mention `\narrower`, which increases the `\left`- and `\rightskip` by `\parindent` so things stay consistent. In the TeXbook exercise 14.15, it is used with a `\smallskip` before and after, as well as an initial `\noindent`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand{\blockquote}[1]{%
  {\narrower\smallskip\noindent#1\smallskip}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[41]
\blockquote{\lipsum[34]}
\lipsum[12]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's easier to take the according code for the `quote` environment from the class file, modify it slightly and create a new environment.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newenvironment{lquote}{%
  \list{}{%
    \rightmargin0pt}%
    \item\relax
  }
{\endlist}

\begin{document}
  \blindtext
  \begin{lquote}
    \blindtext
  \end{lquote}
  \blindtext
\end{document}
```

Note that the [blindtext](http://ctan.org/pkg/blindtext) package is only use for producing dummy text thus not part of the solution.

Answer (score 3):

By using the `changepage` package, one could achieve the same result:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{changepage}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{adjustwidth*}{4em}{2em}
  \lipsum[2]

  \lipsum[3]
\end{adjustwidth*}

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also just delete `\parbox{4in}` (and leave `{}` around `#1`) in your code; then it'll work. And no, guessing the `\parbox` width is definitely not best practice.