# Indenting a whole paragraph

Tags: indentation, paragraphs

How do I indent a whole paragraph at the same distance from my left margin, with the simplest command or environment?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Without any additional packages, you could wrap your paragraph in a `minipage`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\hfill\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-3cm}
\lipsum[2]
\xdef\tpd{\the\prevdepth}
\end{minipage}

\prevdepth\tpd\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
​
```

In the above example, the paragraph depth correction (via `\prevdepth` is from [How to keep a constant baselineskip when using minipages (or \parboxes)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34971/how-to-keep-a-constant-baselineskip-when-using-minipages-or-parboxes)).

The indent from the left is set to `3cm`, but can be modified. Also, if a paragraph indent is required, use `\indent` within the minipage. All of the afore-mentioned modification can be automated. One caveat is that it will not allow breaking across the page boundary.

---

A rather crude way of doing it as well is to modify `\leftskip`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\setlength{\leftskip}{3cm}

\lipsum[2]

\setlength{\leftskip}{0pt}

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
​
```

Comment: Crude as in simple, or ugly?

Comment: @AymanElmasry: It depends on what is contained between the modification. If nothing else uses `\leftskip`, then it is perfectly okay. Big layout changes such as that is usually put in an environment to either make it localized (so it reverts back to normal *after* the environment), or in some macro so that you have more control over it in a general setting... rather than just have length modifications mid-document. However, this all depends on the end-use.

Comment: you also need to adjust the spacing between the preceding paragraph and the indented one.  this one doesn't look too bad, but if the last line of the preceding paragraph were longer, and had no descenders, it would look pretty awful.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Agreed minipage is wrong for this and it can also end up at the bottom of the page and disappear. What is wrong using just `\narrower`?.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Sure, I guess an ending `\strut` would do.

Comment: Another reason for not using a `minipage` in this case is that the OP may want to allow page-breaks in the indented paragraphs.

Comment: @Yiannis -- `\narrower` indents on the right as well as the left.  as i understand the question, indentation is wanted only on the left.  `\leftskip <dimen>` set off in a group ending with `\par` would do that; might need `\noindent` at the beginning.

Comment: In line with the minipage thinking - I tried `{quote}` as well, and it seems to work on short listings...

Answer (score 102):

You could use the `adjustwidth` environment from `changepage` package- a MWE follows. Note that `adjustwidth` environment deals with page breaks.

The `adjustwidth` environment takes 2 arguments: the first is the indent from the left margin, and the second is the indent from the right margin. See the documentation for more details.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{lipsum}       % for sample text
\usepackage{changepage}   % for the adjustwidth environment

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{adjustwidth}{2cm}{}
\lipsum[1]
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{document}
```

If you plan to use this idea a lot, then it's probably worth defining your own environment

```
\newenvironment{myenv}{\begin{adjustwidth}{2cm}{}}{\end{adjustwidth}}
```

which could be used as

```
\begin{myenv}
\lipsum[1]
\end{myenv}
```

---

Following Werner's comment, you could make your environment take an optional argument that would overwrite the default indentation:

```
\newenvironment{myenv}[1][2cm]{\begin{adjustwidth}{#1}{}}{\end{adjustwidth}}
```

Answer (score 53):

Perhaps the easiest way to do that is to use `\begin{quote} ... \end{quote}` environment. It has a pretty similar effect:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{quote}
\lipsum[2]
\end{quote}

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image: Image Example of the Compiled Code]

Comment: This, as well as the addmargin example, are my favourite because they allow both left and right indentation at the same time.

Answer (score 31):

In the KOMA classes, or with the `scrextend` package loaded, you can use the `addmargin` or `addmargin*` environments. The latter is for two sided layouts. The environment takes two arguments, the first being optional. Without the optional argument, the mandatory argument sets the indentation on both sides, while the optional argument specifies the left (or inner, for two sided layouts) indentation.

```
% Option 1: some other class and scrextend
% \documentclass{article}
% \usepackage{scrextend}
% end option 1

% Option 2: use a KOMA class
\documentclass{scrartcl}
% end, option 2

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{addmargin}[2cm]{0cm}
\lipsum[2]
\end{addmargin}
\begin{addmargin}{2cm}
\lipsum[3]
\end{addmargin}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 21):

You can use the `\parshape` primitive:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\parshape 1 2cm \dimexpr\linewidth-2cm\relax
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: It only affects that one paragraph and not the following ones?

Answer (score 14):

You can use the plain TeX command  `\narrower`. You can also use `\hangindent` and `\hangafter` for a bit more control if you wish.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\narrower
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

You can also define a short margin to achieve the opposite effect:

```
\def\wider{%
   \advance\leftskip -\parindent
   \advance\rightskip -\parindent}
```

Comment: How do you reverse the \narrower command after the desired part has been modified?

Comment: @AymanElmasry: you can keep the effect local by grouping: `{\narrower
\lipsum*[1]\par}`

Comment: @AymanElmasry You can use {} to keep the effects local as Gonzalo mentioned, normally I use a small macro called `\wider`. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 13):

Just in case somebody ends up here seeking a ConTeXt answer:

```
\startnarrower[left=2cm, right=3cm]
    There was a sigh in the air that grew to a mutter, and a mutter that 
    grew to a roar, and a roar that passed all sense of hearing, and the 
    hillside on which the villagers stood was hit in the darkness, and 
    rocked to the blow.
\stopnarrower
```

Or, to specify the narrowing for both sides at once:

```
% 2cm narrower on each side, 4cm in total
\startnarrower[middle=2cm]
    Then a note as steady, deep, and true as the deep C of the organ 
    drowned everything for perhaps five minutes, while the very roots of the 
    pines quivered to it. It died away, and the sound of the rain falling on 
    miles of hard ground and grass changed to the muffled drum of water on 
    soft earth. That told its own tale.
\stopnarrower
```

(Example text from Kipling's "The Miracle of Purun Bhagat", from The Second Jungle Book.)

Answer (score 3):

[`xgalley`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xgalley) (or `l3galley`) provides a similar means to adjust margins either *relative* to the current margins or in an *absolute* way. Below I've used the latter:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
% http://river-valley.zeeba.tv/media/conferences/tug-2015/0302-Joseph-Wright/
\usepackage{xgalley}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \SetAbsMargins \galley_margins_set_absolute:nn % {<left margin>}{<right margin>}
\cs_new_eq:NN \SetRelMargins \galley_margins_set_relative:nn % {<left margin>}{<right margin>}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\kant[1]

\begingroup
\SetAbsMargins{3cm}{0pt}

\kant[2]
\endgroup

\kant[3]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I have tried a few of the solutions above. A lot of them cause the error/warning

```
Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item
```

This is due to the fact that the `\adjustwidth` and `\addmargin` (as well as the `quote` and `quotation` environment( internally use something as a list enviroment, which causes if the indendented region contains new paragraphs. (Reference http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-errmissitem.html)

I have found a solution which worked better in this case (taken from http://texblog.net/latex-archive/uncategorized/changing-margins-paragraph/):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\parindent0em
\parskip\baselineskip
\begin{document}
\blindtext

\par
\begingroup
\leftskip4em
\rightskip\leftskip
\blindtext
\par
\endgroup

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

The  important part is in between `\begingroup` and `\endgroup`.  Currently this causes equal left and right indentation by 4em, but you can set the `\rightskip` to something else or leave it out entirely.