# ident a paragraph that following a title

Tags: latex-misc

I would like achieve what is below :

**subject :** A line that i would like to be ident because it is long and i want the part under (subject) is >>>>>>>ident.

The ">>>>>>" is the here for make the tabulation visible.

Comment: Hi!
Does this solve your problem? (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45501/how-to-add-indentation)

Comment: @vinzza no i does not, i do not want the word "subject" be idented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the package *enumitem* make the job !

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setdescription{style=sameline,leftmargin=1.4in}

....

\begin{description}
\item[\underline{subject :}]A line that i would like to be ident because it is long and i want the part under (subject) is ident.
\end{description}
```

[image]