# aligning question numbers, paragraphs

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I am typing up a sheet of course problems, and wanted to offset the question numbers from the text of my solutions slightly.

Based upon an answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35933/indenting-a-whole-paragraph), I tried adjusting leftskip. The code is below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts}
\begin{document}

\noindent 14.5) \\

\setlength{\leftskip}{8mm} \noindent Suppose that $f(a) = f(b)$. This says that $2a + 4 = 2b + 4$, so subtracting \noindent 4 from each side and dividing by 2 yields $a = b$. We conclude that $f$ is injective. \\\\
\noindent Suppose that $c \in E$. This says $2|c $; since $\mathbb{Z}$ distributes multiplication over addition, we have (where $c = 2d$)

\begin{equation*}
c - 4 = 2d - 2(2) = 2(d-2),
\end{equation*}

\vspace{2mm}

 \noindent so $c-4$ is divisible by 2; therefore $\frac{c-4}{2} \in \mathbb{Z}$. But then $f(\frac{c-4}{2})$ clearly equals $c$; so $E \subseteq f[\mathbb{Z}]$. This means that $f$ is surjective. \\\\
 \noindent We conclude that $f$ is a bijection from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $E$. \\

\setlength{\leftskip}{0mm} \noindent 9.10)\\

\setlength{\leftskip}{8mm} \noindent The first statement is false (take $a=3$, $b=8$ to see that there is an integer - namely, 6 - which is in $\mathcal{D}_{ab}$ but not in $\mathcal{D}_a \bigcup \mathcal{D}_b$); the second statement is true, since $p \in \mathcal{PD}_{ab} \implies p \in \mathcal{PD}_a \lor p \in \mathcal{PD}_b$ by Euclid's Lemma (and thus $p \in \mathcal{PD}_a \bigcup \mathcal{PD}_b$), while $p \in \mathcal{PD}_{a} \bigcup \mathcal{PD}_b \implies p|a \lor p|b$, either of which says $p|ab$, so that $p \in \mathcal{PD}_{ab}$. (The second statement follows from these implications.)\\

\setlength{\leftskip}{0mm} \noindent 6.1)\\

\setlength{\leftskip}{8mm} \noindent We show that the $n$ consecutive integers following $(n+1)! + 2$, $n \geq 2$, are composite. Let $S = \{(n+1) + k: 2 \leq k \leq n+1 \}$, and let $K = \{k : 2 \leq k \leq n+1 \}$; it is clear that $S$ is a set of $n$ consecutive integers. Taking any $k$ in $K$, we consider the (obvious) corresponding $s_k = (n+1)! + k \in S$; since $k|(n+1)!$ and $k|k$, we have $k|s_k$; the quotient $\frac{(n+1)!}{k} + 1$ is greater than 1, so each $s_k$ in $S$ thus admits a non-trivial factorization (i.e., is composite). \\

\setlength{\leftskip}{0mm} \noindent 6.2)\\

\setlength{\leftskip}{8mm} \noindent We have 

\begin{eqnarray*}
n^4 + 4 &=& (n^4 + 4n^2 + 4) -4n^2 \\ &=& (n^2 + 2)^2 - (2n)^2\\
&=&(n^2 - 2n + 2)(n^2 + 2n + 2);
\end{eqnarray*}

\vspace{1mm} \noindent both factors are nontrivial for $n \geq 2$. \\

\setlength{\leftskip}{0mm} \noindent 6.5) \\ 
\setlength{\leftskip}{8mm} 

\noindent If we had $d > 1: d|m, n$, then we would have $m = \mu d, n = \nu d$; 

\end{document}
```

The code was fine for its intended purpose on the first page; however, on the second page, it no longer dedented the question numbers in the way I wanted. (They appeared directly above the solution text, despite my using the same commands as on the first page.)

What's going on here? How can I get my desired effect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*@user1296727: please don't take the following remarks personally; one learns from one's own errors and you, as a teacher, know this well.* :-)

---

This is completely against LaTeX philosophy, where *logical structures* should be marked and then their typesetting can be defined once and for all of them.

Here's a proposal.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts}

\newcommand{\relor}{\mathrel{\lor}}
\newcommand{\divis}{\,|\,}
\newenvironment{solution}[1]
  {\par\addvspace{\medskipamount}
   \noindent\makebox[0pt][r]{#1) }\ignorespaces}
  {\par\addvspace{\medskipamount}}

\begin{document}

\begin{solution}{14.5}
Suppose that $f(a) = f(b)$. This says that $2a + 4 = 2b + 4$, so subtracting $4$ 
from each side and dividing by $2$ yields $a = b$. We conclude that $f$ is injective.

Suppose that $c \in E$. This says $2\divis c$; since $\mathbb{Z}$ distributes 
multiplication over addition, we have (where $c = 2d$)
\begin{equation*}
c - 4 = 2d - 2(2) = 2(d-2),
\end{equation*}
so $c-4$ is divisible by $2$; therefore $\frac{c-4}{2} \in \mathbb{Z}$. 
But then $f(\frac{c-4}{2})$ clearly equals $c$; so $E \subseteq f[\mathbb{Z}]$. 
This means that $f$ is surjective. 

We conclude that $f$ is a bijection from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $E$.
\end{solution}

\begin{solution}{9.10}
The first statement is false (take $a=3$, $b=8$ to see that there is an 
integer --~namely, 6~-- which is in $\mathcal{D}_{ab}$ but not in 
$\mathcal{D}_a \cup \mathcal{D}_b$); the second statement is true, 
since $p \in \mathcal{PD}_{ab} \implies p \in \mathcal{PD}_a \relor p \in \mathcal{PD}_b$ 
by Euclid's Lemma (and thus $p \in \mathcal{PD}_a \cup \mathcal{PD}_b$), while 
$p \in \mathcal{PD}_{a} \cup \mathcal{PD}_b \implies p\divis a \relor p\divis b$, either of which 
says $p\divis ab$, so that $p \in \mathcal{PD}_{ab}$. (The second statement follows from 
these implications.)
\end{solution}

\begin{solution}{6.1}
We show that the $n$ consecutive integers following $(n+1)! + 2$, $n \geq 2$, are 
composite. Let $S = \{(n+1) + k: 2 \leq k \leq n+1 \}$, and let 
$K = \{k : 2 \leq k \leq n+1 \}$; it is clear that $S$ is a set of $n$ consecutive 
integers. Taking any $k$ in $K$, we consider the (obvious) corresponding 
$s_k = (n+1)! + k \in S$; since $k\divis(n+1)!$ and $k\divis k$, we have $k\divis s_k$;
the quotient $\frac{(n+1)!}{k} + 1$ is greater than 1, so each $s_k$ in $S$ thus 
admits a non-trivial factorization (i.e., is composite).
\end{solution}

\begin{solution}{6.2}
We have 
\begin{align*}
n^4 + 4 &= (n^4 + 4n^2 + 4) -4n^2 \\
&= (n^2 + 2)^2 - (2n)^2\\
&= (n^2 - 2n + 2)(n^2 + 2n + 2);
\end{align*}
both factors are nontrivial for $n \geq 2$.
\end{solution}

\begin{solution}{6.5}
If we had $d > 1: d\divis m, n$, then we would have $m = \mu d, n = \nu d$; 
\end{solution}

\end{document}
```

There is much less white space, but the numbers in the margin stick out and this is sufficient to give the required emphasis.

Notice the definitions of `\divis` and `\relor`: padding the bar with some space helps in distinguishing the object; you're using `\lor` as a relation symbol, so it's best to tell LaTeX it is.

Never use `\\` for producing white vertical space and never separate displayed equations from the text above them; it depends on the text whether it should be separated with a blank line from the text below it.

[image]

---

How do we get the labels in the margin? The `solution` environment wants the label as its argument; then it does `\par` to be sure about LaTeX's state and adds a vertical spacing (read on for `\addvspace`). The paragraph is started by `\noindent`, followed by a box of zero width with its contents pushed to its right margin: since there is no space, the text will stick out on the left.

The `\ignorespaces` is needed because otherwise the end-of-line in

```
\begin{solution}{14.5}
```

would create an extra space which would go in front of "Suppose"; so we kill it.

At the end of the environment, `\par` ends whatever paragraph was being built and issues another vertical space. However, `\addvspace` is used, so two consecutive `solution` environments will be separated by just *one* of those vertical spaces. In general, when two `\addvspace` are next to each other, the maximum amoung wins.

---

If you prefer that the solution text is indented (which I don't recommend), you can use the same code as before, just changing the definition of `solution`, for example with the help of the `enumitem` package:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlength{\sollabel}
\AtBeginDocument{
  \settowidth{\sollabel}{00.00) }
}
\newenvironment{solution}[1]
  {\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=\sollabel,labelwidth=*]\item[#1)]}
  {\end{itemize}}
```

This should show *why* it's better to use "logical structures", instead of marking manually the spacings and everything else. A mock paragraph has been added to show the result.

[image]

---

About `\leftskip`: TeX typesets a paragraph with only one value of `\leftskip`, namely the one which is current at the end of the paragraph. With

```
\setlength{\leftskip}{0mm} \noindent 6.5) \\ 
\setlength{\leftskip}{8mm} 

\noindent If we had $d > 1: d|m, n$, then we would have $m = \mu d, n = \nu d$;
```

the paragraph ends at the empty line after `\setlength{\leftskip}{8mm}`, because `\\` *doesn't* end paragraphs. In the original code there's an empty line before `\setlength{\leftskip}{8mm}` in the other cases.

Comment: Purely for interest, why doesn't the `\leftskip` take effect at the start of the second page in the OP's example?

Comment: Could you explain how the environment which you defined allowed you to attach the labels which you did, and what the parameters in your definition mean?

Comment: OK I get it now. The change to `leftskip` does take effect, and everything on the second page is indented, which makes it look at first glance as though nothing is indented.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this happens, but what is clear is that this is a very awkward method. Surely you would be off better using an `itemize` environment (see section 2.11.1 of the [Not so Short Guide to LaTeX](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/lshort/english) for details). In my opinion, starting the text below the numbers does not look very good. Nevertheless, it is not difficult to achieve this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\dropitem[1]{\item[#1]\leavevmode\vskip1em}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\dropitem{14.5)} Some material that is more than one line long, so we can see
                 that the indentation is still correct.
\dropitem{9.10)} More stuff
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```