# Why does indenting a paragraph compound on subsequent paragraphs?

Tags: indentation

I'm attempting to indent cases and subcases of a proof by 1.3cm. However, when I [apply `adjustwidth`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35934/19616) to a subcase, it seems to affect the subcase following it.

Here is how it looks with my current code:

[image: Case 2.2 indented too far]

And here's how I'd like it to look:

[image: Case 2.2 indented correctly]

Code I'm using (excuse the sloppy reuse of code):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{changepage}
\begin{document}
    \begin{proof}
        {\it Case 1.} First case.

        \begin{adjustwidth}{1.3cm}{}
            Case explanation.
        \end{adjustwidth}

        {\it Case 2.} Second case.

        \begin{adjustwidth}{1.3cm}{}
            {\it Case 2.1.} First part.

            {\it Case 2.2.} Second part.

            \begin{adjustwidth}{1.3cm}{}
                Second part explanation.
            \end{adjustwidth}
        \end{adjustwidth}
    \end{proof}
\end{document}
```

How can I adjust my code to allow uniform indenting of sections? If it's not possible with `adjustwidth`, what can I use?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: `{\it Case 2.1.}` This should just be a list (and `\it` is a deprecated command anyway) LaTeX list environments will handle the indentation and numbering automatically.

Comment: Please see also [Does it matter if I use \textit or \it, \bfseries or \bf, etc](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516) — `\it` is deprecated in LaTeX2e, better to use `{\itshape …}` or just `\textit{…}`. — Why don’t you use a simple list like `enumerate`?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I've adjusted the example. As for the `\it` and `\bf`, this is just a sample, not "production" typesetting code. As for a list, I don't think it will work for my case since the word `Case` has to be prepended and it has to work in a `proof` environment.

Comment: Eric you are already using `adjustwidth` which is a latex list environment, but with an empty label, but then labelling the cases by hand, I just suggest using a list environment with a label that does the numbering, so that numbering and cross referencing is more natural.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code will yield the desired output however as said in the comments of your question you might want the review some of your code in order to remove the `\it` commands and replace them by `{\itshape }` for instance

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{changepage}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
    \textit{Case 1.} First case.

    \begin{adjustwidth}{1.3cm}{}
        Case explanation.
    \end{adjustwidth}

    \textit{Case 2.} Second case.

    \begin{adjustwidth}{1.3cm}{}
        \textit{Case 2.1.} First part.\\
        \textit{Case 2.2.} Second part.

        \begin{adjustwidth}{1.3cm}{}
            Second part explanation.
        \end{adjustwidth}
    \end{adjustwidth}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

The "bad" indenting came from the new paragraph introduced by the empty line between Case 2.1 and Case 2.2. This can be visualised if you add `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` in your preamble. Then the "bad" indent is still there but is of 0pt which gives the desired output.

Comment: Is there any specific reason why the double-\ newline forces the proper formatting while a "paragraph" newline does not?

Comment: I would say that the new paragraph introduces an indent which you don't want while the newline does not.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you! I will accept your answer when the timeout expires.

Comment: For instance with your MWE and by adding `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` in your preamble you will get the desired output.

Comment: It should be `\textit{Case 2.}` and nothing else. `;-)` You don't want to use obsolete commands, do you?

Comment: @egreg As I said in the comments on the question, this is just a sample and not "production" code. ;)

Comment: @egreg I will edit my answer to try to have it "up-to-date".

Answer (score 8):

You should almost never need manual numbering, indentation or `\\` in a LaTeX document. If you let the system do this it is much easier to handle cross references, and get consistent layouts, or to change the layouts without editing the document body.

Here I use some basic settings in `enumitem` to save setting the lower level latex list parameters directly. The package has a lot of parameters so the exact indentation style can be customised more without changing the document markup.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{pcases}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist[pcases]{label=\textit{Case \arabic*},leftmargin=*}
\setlist[pcases,2]{label=\textit{\thepcasesi.\arabic*}}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}\mbox{}
    \begin{pcases}
    \item First case.

        Case explanation.

    \item Second case.
        \begin{pcases}
        \item First part.
        \item Second part.

            Second part explanation.
        \end{pcases}
    \end{pcases}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```