# How to reduce page margins and center text on it?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, margins

I need a custom title page, where the margins create a tighter area for the page contents and a title text is centered horizontally and vertically. How do I do that?

By tighter margins I mean margins that differ from my regular document margins (set in the \document command).

Comment: do you mean something like: [Indenting a whole paragraph](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35933)

Comment: Ok, how do I "indent" it from the right then?

Comment: did you see my answer? :) use the `adjustwidth` environment from the `changepage` package

Comment: What will you placing "centered horizontally and vertically"? A single title, or perhaps more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `\newgeometry` and `\restoregeometry` commands  from the  `geometry` package with a code like this one:

```
\newgeometry{centering,margin=1.5cm}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\mbox{}\vfill
\begin{center}
  \Huge\bfseries My Lovely Title
\end{center}
\vfill \mbox{}
\restoregeometry
```

These commands start a new page:

[image]