# indentation of a whole paragraph

Tags: indentation, paragraphs

My problem is that I would like to write something like in LaTeX:
[image]

But I can't seem to do it wihtout reading like:
[image]

Which is pretty anoying to do all the time, in the middle of writting. Is there a code to do it for a whole paragraph without written \hspace*{1,5 cm} in middle of a sentence

Comment: Welcome, is that supposed to be something like a list? A little bit information on what you are trying to do (not just how it is supposed to look like) helps in providing a robust solution.

Comment: have you seen [Indenting a whole paragraph](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35933) seems fairly close

Comment: See also [paragraphs - Indent a whole section - all lines but the first - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/370816/indent-a-whole-section-all-lines-but-the-first)

Answer (score 9):

There is a pair `\hangindent` and `\hangafter`.  In your case (I am not sure, if the indentation should start immediately or after the first line of a paragraph)

```
\hangindent=1.5cm
\hangafter=1 %after which line the indentations starts
```

gives the expected result.

Comment: Thank you, just what I needed. Out of curiosity is it possibly to 'stop' the \hangindent again?

Comment: @Helene Yes, for example `\hangindent0mm`, when you need the null  value. (Is it the meaning of your "stop"?)

Comment: Yes that was exactly what i meant

Answer (score 3):

There is also the hanging package which works well.

\hangpara is called as width and then a positive value indents the left a negative intends at the right of the text. The second parameter is the number of lines to indent (it can also be negative - read manual).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for mock text
\usepackage{hanging}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[2]
\hangpara{1.5cm}{1}This one is hanging \lipsum*[3]
\lipsum[4]
\hangpara{1.0cm}{2}This one has two lines hanging but less so \lipsum*[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic implementation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for mock text

\newenvironment{helene}% <--- choose a more informative name
 {\begin{itemize}[label={},leftmargin=1.5cm,itemindent=-1.5cm]\item}
 {\end{itemize}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{helene}
\lipsum*[3]
\end{helene}

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]