# Indent a whole section - all lines but the first

Tags: paragraphs

I want to do something like this - any idea of how?
So the idea is, that all but the first line should be indent [image]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! 
See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3254054/latex-indent-from-second-line or [hanging package](http://ctan.org/pkg/hanging)!

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99344/indent-text-after-line-1

Answer (score 7):

That is the standard layout of the `description` list.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
\item[Validation Analysis (VA)] Zzzzz zzz zzz zzzz zzzz
zz zzzzz zzzz zzzzzzzz zzzzz zzzz zzzzzzzz zzzzz zzzz zzzzzz
zz zzzzz zzzz zzzzzzzz zzzzz zzzz zzzzzzzz zzzzz zzzz zzzzzz
zz zzzzz zzzz zzzzzzzz zzzzz zzzz zzzzzzzz zzzzz zzzz zzzzzz
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

The `hanging` package and the `hangparas` environment is what you are looking for.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hanging}
\begin{document}
  \begin{hangparas}{1em}{1}
    \lipsum
  \end{hangparas}
\end{document}
```

but you could also set the following in your preamble to influence the whole document:

```
\leftskip=1em
\parindent=-1em
```

In both cases you get an output looking like this:

[image]

Comment: it's probably not a good idea to set `\leftskip` directly in latex, it will get reset in all sorts of places.

Comment: (example leftskip breaks) https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108327/ alternative includes e.g. [`\hangafter`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35946/250119)