# Changing margin for a part of page only

Tags: graphics, margins, geometry

I would like to change the margin for an image only, I've used

```
\newgeometry{left=0.5cm,bottom=0.1cm,right=0.5cm}
\includegraphics{tada.png}
\restoregeometry
```

But it affects an entire page

Comment: The fullwidth package could help; see https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fullwidth?lang=en

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35933/indenting-a-whole-paragraph

Comment: is the image wider or narrower than the usual text block?  it should be possible to pack it into a `minipage` and use positive or negative `\hspaces` to "adjust" the apparent size of the `minipage`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank's to comment I got it to work using minipage and negative \hspace

```
  \begin{figure}\centering
    \begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth}
    \hspace{-2.85cm}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.55]{Organigramme.png}
    \end{minipage}
  \end{figure}
```

Comment: Don't put a `figure` environment inside a `center` environment like that, the figure could easily float away, and then you're left with some unwanted vertical space generated by the `center` environment. To center the contents of a `figure` environment add `\centering` right after `\begin{figure}`.

Comment: The `minipage` is not needed; just use `\hspace*{<dim>}%`

Answer (score 1):

for local extension of text width for one equation or image you can use `changepage` package and his macro `adjustwidth`:

```
% preamble ...
\usepackage[sctrict]{changepage}
% ...

\begin{figure}
    \begin{adjustwidth}{0.5cm}{0.5cm}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Organigramme.png}
    \end{adjustwidth}
  \end{figure}
% ...
```