# Manual adjustment of (left) margin for GRAPHIC in APPENDIX

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment, margins, appendices

I would like to include a graphic into one of my appendix section. The problem is that I need the graphic to be as large as possible in order for some writing in it to be legible. I noticed that the graphic automatically moves across the right page margin as I scale it up. However, I want the graphic to be in a central position, so I suppose I would have to adjust the left margin manually? My code looks as follows:

```
\begin{appendices}
   \section{Appendix A}
   \section{Appendix B}
   \section{Appendix C}
      \includegraphics[width=???mm]{"graphic"}
\end{appendices}
```

I have already tried out the what is proposed in the answers to [Changing margin for a part of page only](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/326158/changing-margin-for-a-part-of-page-only), but neither solution worked in the appendix environment. (When I include a figure into the appendix via `\begin{figure} \end{figure}` it paradoxically appears outside of it.)

I would be very grateful for any answers or suggestions! :)

P.S. In case it is of any importance, I am using the `article class`.

Comment: I am wondering about `width=300mm`? Which paper format do you use? `A3` (which would be quite unusual). Neither `letter` nor `A4` formats allow for text widths (or linewidths) larger than about `18cm` (having some `1.5cm` of margins to the left and right, as an example

Comment: @Christian Hupfer I just put down something. I'm using A4. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\includegraphics` has no special positioning rules: it gets placed on the page just like a letter and so the same mechanisms can be used to adjust the position as you would use to position a letter.

Probably here you just want `\hspace`.

```
\hspace*{-2cm}\includegraphics[width=15cm]\hspace*{-2cm}
```

For example would allow a 15cm wide image starting 2cm to the left of wherever it would have started otherwise.

Comment: Why the `\hspace*{-2cm}` at the end? I would have put `\hspace*{2cm}`...

Comment: @CarLaTeX the OP asked for it to remain centred so you need to take the same space off both sides

Comment: I was sure there was an explanation :)