# Tab a Complete Paragraph

Tags: beamerposter

don't get mad please as I always don't share a MWE. Actually, I am working on a LaTeX file which has several themes associated to it and so it is a bit difficult to put up a MWE.

What I wanted to inquire is that how to Slightly Tab a complete paragraph horizontally. I am using \quad and it just tab the first line but not the rest of the lines of the paragraph.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0` before the paragraph.

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35933/indenting-a-whole-paragraph help?

Comment: So, \hangindent=2em\hangafter=0 solved the problem. Thanks to TeXnician