# Fully justification with indent paragraph

Tags: indentation, paragraphs

I am using the package `ragged2e` and then `\justify` to get fully justification of my text but it's seems that is avoiding the indentation.

My code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,onecolumn]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{indentfirst}

\begin{document}

\maketitle % Utilizando a página de capa padrão

\begin{chapter}{Introdução}

 \begin{justify}
 \begin{setlength}{\parindent}{4cm}
 \fontsize{10pt}{1pt}\selectfont
 Os problemas inversos de transferência de calor (IHTP) dependem de medições de temperatura e/ou 
 fluxo de calor para a estimativa de quantidades desconhecidas que aparecem na análise de problemas físicos em engenharia térmica. 
 Como exemplo, problemas inversos que lidam com a condução de calor têm sido geralmente associados à estimativa de um fluxo de calor 
 limite desconhecido, usando medições de temperatura feitas abaixo da superfície do limite. Portanto, enquanto no problema 
 clássico de condução direta de calor a causa (fluxo de calor limite) é dada e o efeito (campo de temperatura no corpo) é 
 determinado, o problema inverso envolve a estimativa da causa a partir do conhecimento do efeito. Uma vantagem do IHTP é 
 que ele permite muito mais colaboração entre pesquisadores experimentais e teóricos, a fim de obter o máximo de informações 
 sobre o problema físico em estudo.
 \end{setlength}
 \end{justify}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But I want all the text justify and with the indentation, some like that:

[image]

Comment: Your question is similar to [Indenting a whole paragraph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35933/5764) (possible duplicate). The suggested method here would be to use the `adjustwidth` environment from [`changepage`](//ctan.org/pkg/changepage).

Comment: `\hangindent5cm\hangafter0 Paragraph ... `

Comment: you have no need for `\begin{justify}` (it is almost never needed0 justification is the default tex behaviour.