# Ragged right TOC entries using \titlecontents* int tufte-book

Tags: titletoc, tufte-book

I am trying to make the subsection entries in a TOC to be grouped together as a paragraph, as provided by the `\titlecontents*` command in the `titletoc` package. See my attempt in this MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{tufte-book}
%\usepackage{titletoc} % Don't need---included with tufte-book

\titlecontents*{subsection}[.5in]
{\addvspace{.5pc}\small\itshape}{}{}{~~\thecontentspage}[\ \ \ \ ]

\begin{document} 

\frontmatter
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{A boring chapter}

\section{A first section}

% Words in section title are separated by ~ to prevent line breaks in titles
\subsection{Corvids~and~jays}

\subsection{Elephants~and~cetaceans}

\subsection{Rosids~and~arachnids}

\end{document}
```

In the document produced, the subsection title "Rosids and arachnids" is broken across a line, with "arachnids" hyphenated:

[image]

I want to force the entire subsection title to go to the next line rather than span it.

I believe the interaction between the `titletoc` package and the `tufte-book` class  affects this, since `tufte-book` requires `titletoc` and I wasn't able to reproduce the problem in a MWE that doesn't use `tufte-book`.

None of the solutions involving `\raggedright` or `\hyphenpenalty` suggested in answers to related questions have worked---again, I suspect it is the `tufte-book` document class that is the factor. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you think of this? I inserted \raggedright after \itshape, and added \mbox to keep the titles together. I see that the subsection content is placed at the left margin, and I still have to figure out how to bring it back to the more right position.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{tufte-book}
%\usepackage{titletoc} % Don't need---included with tufte-book

\titlecontents*{subsection}[.5in]
{\addvspace{.5pc}\small\itshape}{}{}{~~\thecontentspage}[\ \
 \ \ ]


\begin{document} 

\frontmatter
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{A boring chapter}

\section{A first section}

% Words in section title are separated by ~ to prevent line breaks in titles
\subsection{Corvids~and~jays}

\subsection{\mbox{Elephants~and~cetaceans}}

\subsection{\mbox{Rosids~and~arachnids}}

\subsection{\mbox{Rosids~and~flowers}}

\subsection{\mbox{Rosids~and~anything else}}

\subsection{\mbox{Rosids~and~even more to do}}

\subsection{\mbox{Rosids~and~how far we should go}}

\subsection{\mbox{Rosids~and~the end of the textwidth}}

\end{document}
```

[image: titlecontents protected with mbox]

Comment: I tried out your two changes (`\raggedright` and `\mbox`) separately. Putting`\raggedright`  at the end of  the "above code" parameter overrides the left placement, as shown in your example. The `\mbox` works by itself without changing the left placement. However, I don't understand these effects, such as why `\raggedright` overrides the left placement. Is there any explanation in terms of `titletoc`'s options?

Comment: Indeed, you can use the \mbox. I do not know, why it did not work the first time when I compiled twice. \raggedright in general ignores previous indentation. At https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35933/indenting-a-whole-paragraph I found this solution to restore the indentation after it: \parshape 1 1.5cm \dimexpr\linewidth-2cm\relax. I deleted the \raggedright in my answer. So, if \mbox for you is the solution, please accept my answer.

Comment: Accepted, thank you. Please also update the image of the results, since the document looks different with the `\raggedright` deleted.