# Indenting the exam question for two different formats correctly

Tags: indentation, exam

I'm trying to align the indentation of questions with two different formats (one for extended responses, the other, multiple choice).
As much as I try, I am stuck using various random numbers to try to align it properly, and I can't figure out how to get the question for the multiple choice aligned - adjusting questionshook will often touch the second question, and seemingly `\renewcommand{\questionshook}` doesn't seem to work in the middle of the document (unlike `\renewcommand{\choiceshook}` etc), which means I can't seem to treat each part standalone.

This is what I have right now:

[image: image of what I have]

This is what I desire:

[image: image of what I desire]

This is my code, which is unfortunately not super short because of the interactions with other questions:

```tex
\documentclass[%
    12pt, 
    a4paper,
]{exam}

\usepackage[showframe=true]{geometry}

\usepackage{calc}
\renewcommand{\questionshook}{%
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
    \labelwidth\leftmargin\advance\labelwidth-\labelsep%
}

% Dimensions tuned to be about right.
\renewcommand{\partshook}{
    \setlength{\topsep}{-0.02in}%
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{\leftmargin+0.08in}%
    \setlength{\labelsep}{0.22in}%
}

\newlength{\mcindent}
\setlength{\mcindent}{0.55cm}

\renewcommand{\choiceshook}{%
% The dimensions are tuned to be about right. I should figure out how to not have random numbers.
    \settowidth{\leftmargin}{W\hspace{\labelsep}\hspace{0.18in}\hspace{\mcindent}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
% multiple choice format
\noqformat
\renewcommand{\thequestion}{\textbf{\arabic{question}}}
% This makebox sort of works for the first line.
\renewcommand{\questionlabel}{\makebox[1cm][l]{\thequestion}}
\pointsinmargin\pointformat{}

% an adjustbox from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35934/200609 does not work properly as all there is some indentation from the number already
\question[1]%
I wish to have both lines of this sentence aligned with the A/B/C/D multiple choice options.

\begin{choices}
\choice Oh really?
\choice Here I will demonstrate how to type a long sentence, to confirm that it works here.
\end{choices}

% extended response format
\qformat{\textbf{Question \thequestion} (\totalpoints\ marks)\hfill}
\pointsinrightmargin
\pointformat{\textbf{\themarginpoints}}

\question%
This question should remain in the same format, aligned to the border. I do no know how to do this whilst doing the choice answer indented using questionshook, since redefining it does not seem to work.
\begin{parts}
\part[1] Ideally the text in these parts should be at the same indent as the multiple choice options, but it is closer enough at the moment that I can ignore it.

\part[2] This is another long sentence to make sure indentation works properly, as I tend to forgot to fix that.
\end{parts}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A newcommand `\questionx` was defined to deal with the second question style. In that way `\qformat` is not needed ouside its scope.

The additional  separation between  the labels and the text (between the blue and red lines) is control by `\xtrasep` (set to 0.7cm for this example). No magic numbers are involved in the solution.

[image: f]

```
\documentclass[%
12pt, 
a4paper,
]{exam}

\usepackage[showframe=true]{geometry}   
\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage{enumitem}% added    

\renewcommand{\questionlabel}{\unskip\bfseries\thequestion}

\newlength{\xtrasep}
\setlength{\xtrasep}{0.7cm} % set blank space beteween label and text
    
\renewcommand{\choiceshook}{% 
\settowidth{\labelwidth}{A.}%   
\setlength{\labelsep}{1em} % after A., B.
\setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelindent+\labelwidth+\labelsep-\itemindent}
}   

\renewcommand{\questionshook}{% 
    \settowidth{\labelwidth}{(m)}%  
    \setlength{\labelsep}{\xtrasep}
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelindent+\labelwidth+\labelsep-\itemindent}
}

\newcommand{\questionx}[1]{% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\qformat{\textbf{Question \thequestion} (\totalpoints\ marks)\hfill}
\pointsinrightmargin
\pointformat{\textbf{\themarginpoints}} 
\question
\hspace*{-\leftmargin}\parbox{\textwidth}{#1}
}
    
\renewcommand{\partshook}{% 
    \settowidth{\labelwidth}{(m)}%  
    \setlength{\labelsep}{\xtrasep}
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}
    \def\makelabel##1{##1}% 
}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{questions}
        % multiple choice format
%       \noqformat
        \pointsinmargin\pointformat{}       

        \question[1]%
        I  wish to have both lines of this sentence aligned with the A/B/C/D multiple choice options.
        
        \begin{choices}
            \choice Oh really?
            \choice Here I will demonstrate how to type a long sentence, to confirm that it works here.
        \end{choices}   
    
    \questionx{%
    This question should remain in the same format, aligned to the border. I do no know how to do this whilst doing the choice answer indented using questionshook, since redefining it does not seem to work.}
    \begin{parts}
        \part[1] Ideally the text in these parts should be at the same indent as the multiple choice options, but it is closer enough at the moment that I can ignore it.
        
        \part[2] This is another long sentence to make sure indentation works properly, as I tend to forgot to fix that.
    \end{parts}
        
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hmm, this seems to have the behaviour of indenting text which was between questions; this seems obvious in hindsight as being treated as part of the question text, however, when googling a solution to that I found `\fullwidth`, which seems to work the same way that `{\hspace*{-\leftmargin}\parbox{\textwidth}{#1}}` does. Is there much of a difference?

Comment: You can try `\question\mbox{}\fullwdthl{#1}` or  `\question \mbox{}\uplevel{#1}` but both will insert a blank line,

Comment: Okay, thanks :)

Comment: You probably don't want a page break in the middle of a question anyway.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to run `\questionshook` more than once, but you have to `\end{questions}` first.

The red line is precisely 1cm from the edge of the text area.

Note, this uses left justified numbers, not right justified numbers shifted left until they look good.

[image: demo]

```
\documentclass[%
    12pt, 
    a4paper,
]{exam}

\usepackage[showframe=true]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{calc}

\renewcommand{\questionshook}{\setlength{\labelwidth}{1cm-\labelsep}%
  \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth+\labelsep}}

\renewcommand{\choiceshook}{\setlength{\labelwidth}{1em}%
  \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth+\labelsep}%
  \setlength{\itemindent}{0pt}}

\renewcommand{\partshook}{\setlength{\labelwidth}{1cm-\labelsep}%
  \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth+\labelsep}%
  \setlength{\itemindent}{0pt}}

\renewcommand{\questionlabel}{\makebox[\labelwidth][l]{\thequestion}}
\renewcommand{\partlabel}{\makebox[\labelwidth][l]{(\thepartno)}}
\renewcommand{\choicelabel}{\makebox[\labelwidth][l]{\thechoice}}
\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
% multiple choice format
\noqformat
\renewcommand{\thequestion}{\textbf{\arabic{question}}}
% This makebox sort of works for the first line.

\pointsinmargin\pointformat{}

% an adjustbox from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35934/200609 does not work properly as all there is some indentation from the number already
\question[1]%
I wish to have both lines of this sentence aligned with the A/B/C/D multiple choice options.

\begin{choices}
\choice Oh really?
\choice Here I will demonstrate how to type a long sentence, to confirm that it works here.
\end{choices}

\xdef\lastquestion{\arabic{question}}
\end{questions}

\renewcommand{\questionshook}{\setlength{\labelwidth}{1cm-\labelsep}% not actually needed
  \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\itemindent}{\labelwidth+\labelsep}}

\begin{questions}
\setcounter{question}{\lastquestion}


% extended response format
\qformat{\textbf{Question \thequestion} (\totalpoints\ marks)\hfill}
\pointsinrightmargin
\pointformat{\textbf{\themarginpoints}}

\question
This question should remain in the same format, aligned to the border. I do no know how to do this whilst doing the choice answer indented using questionshook, since redefining it does not seem to work.

\begin{parts}
\part[1] 
Ideally the text in these parts should be at the same indent as the multiple choice options, but it is closer enough at the moment that I can ignore it.

\part[2] This is another long sentence to make sure indentation works properly, as I tend to forgot to fix that.
\end{parts}

\fullwidth{\hspace{1cm}\smash{\textcolor{red}{\rule{0.5pt}{9cm}}}}% show alignment

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have gone with another solution, as this does not align the indented parts correctly.

Comment: OTOH, it does greatly simplify the code.  Not sure what "correctly" implies.

Comment: The long-form questions parts are not indented.

Answer (score 2):

We the use of the `\uplevel` command

```
\documentclass[%
    12pt, 
    a4paper,
]{exam}

\usepackage[showframe=true]{geometry}

\usepackage{calc}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand{\questionshook}{%

\setlength{\labelsep}{8.2mm}
     \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep+\labelwidth}
    
 }

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Dimensions tuned to be about right.
\renewcommand{\partshook}{
     \setlength{\topsep}{-0.02in}%
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 \renewcommand{\choiceshook}{%
 \setlength{\leftmargin}{8.2mm}
}

% remove unwanted spaces before labels
\renewcommand{\questionlabel}{\unskip\thequestion.}
\renewcommand{\choicelabel}{\unskip\thechoice.}

\begin{document}


\begin{questions}

\pointsinmargin\pointformat{}


\question[1]% 

I wish to have both lines of this sentence aligned with the A/B/C/D multiple choice options.

\begin{choices}
\choice Oh really?
\choice Here I will demonstrate how to type a long sentence, to confirm that it works here.
\end{choices}

% extended response format
\qformat{\textbf{Question \thequestion} (\totalpoints\ marks)\hfill}
\pointsinrightmargin
\pointformat{\textbf{\themarginpoints}}

\question \mbox{}
\uplevel{%
This question should remain in the same format, aligned to the border. I do no know how to do this whilst doing the choice answer indented using questionshook, since redefining it does not seem to work.}

\begin{parts}
\part[1] Ideally the text in these parts should be at the same indent as the multiple choice options, but it is closer enough at the moment that I can ignore it.

\part[2] This is another long sentence to make sure indentation works properly, as I tend to forgot to fix that.
\end{parts}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What's the difference here between \uplevel and the solution by @Simon Dispa which is `\hspace*{-\leftmargin}\parbox{\textwidth}{#1}`?