# \leftskip, \linewidth and minipage

Tags: minipage, lengths

I have an environment with a `minipage`of the length `\linewidth-\parindent` (using the `calc` package). When I stick this in a place where `\leftskip=\parindent` it protrudes in the margin. Shouldn't `\linewidth` adapt to these new dimensions and keep the minipage inside the margin?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{calc}

\newenvironment{env}
    {\hfill\begin{minipage}{\linewidth-\parindent}\bf}
    {\end{minipage}}

\begin{document}

\tiny

\blindtext

\begin{env}
\blindtext
\end{env}

\blindtext

\setlength{\leftskip}{\parindent}

\blindtext

\begin{env}
\blindtext
\end{env}

\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT: With the hints from David I found what I needed from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4959/how-do-i-indent-all-lines-of-a-paragraph-so-that-it-looks-like-a-blockquote/4970#4970) (is this a duplicate?):

```
\newenvironment{env}
    {\list{}{}\item\relax
    \nointerlineskip\leavevmode}
    {\endlist}
```

This indents the margin via `list` (like LaTeXs `quote`) and `\nointerlineskip\leavevmode` fixes problems with missing items.

Comment: Have you considered using the `changepage` package? It will surely do what you want to achieve. Tell me if you want me to post a MWE or if you want to give it a try first then that's fine as well. By the way, try using `\bfseries` instead of `\bf`. Just a suggestion.

Comment: When I use `changepage` and `adjustwidth` I get 'maybe a missing \item' error messages with line references to what seems to be all `\label` commands.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you set a TeX primitive register such as `\leftskip` then nothing is recalculated not `\linewidth` or `\leftmargin` or `\@totaleftmargin` that is why LaTeX has a list structure and a `list` environment to set all these parameters to consistent value.

If you want an indented region, do not set `\leftskip` use `quote` or a similarly defined environment.

Never set `\leftskip` directly in latex you will break almost all its display constructs (not just your own definitions).

Answer (score 1):

Though probably different from what the OP is asking, the following is just a suggestion using the `changepage` package to achieve the indented paragraphs. Hope it helps. A little bit more insight as to the usage of the environment would help to provide a more suitable solution. Referencing is possible.

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{changepage}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-1]
\begin{adjustwidth*}{0.25\linewidth}{}
\lipsum[1-1]
\begin{equation}
    E=mc^2 \label{eq1}
\end{equation}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item one \label{item1}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{adjustwidth*}
Reference Equation~\ref{eq1}. Reference Item~\ref{item1}.

\lipsum[1-1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just a note the adjustwidth package does use a list to set the paragraph text