# Using `\list` to indent subsections

Tags: lists, indentation

I want to indent all of the subsections my document. After some trial, error and reading I got the impression, that `\list` is the way to do this (see MWE below). (Eventually, I want to absorb this into the `\subsection` command, but for demonstration, this seems clearer). However, when a heading directly precedes the `\begin{list}` (as is often the case for me), I get the error `Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.`.

Adding `\nointerlineskip\leavevmode` after `\item\relax` (as suggested in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183569/leftskip-linewidth-and-minipage)) removes this error but breaks the spacing between the headings.

Why exactly do I get the error message? How can I avoid it without breaking the spacing between the headings?

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{foo}
\lipsum[4]

% uncommenting the following \section causes an error:
%\section{foo}
\begin{list}{}{\advance\leftskip 5ex}
\item\relax

\subsection{bar}
\lipsum[4]

\[
    a^n + b^n = c^n
\]

\lipsum[2]

\begin{enumerate}
    \item one
    \item two
    \item three
\end{enumerate}

\end{list}

\lipsum[4]


\end{document}
```

Comment: Something like `\section` etc. should not appear in a `list`

Comment: Since the standard way of changing indentation seems to be with lists: Does this mean, I cannot (easily) indent parts of the document that contain sectioning commands?

Comment: Regarding the error see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237551/indent-text-without-using-trivlist

Comment: I suggest that you look into the titlesec package, it's quite versatile to control things like formatting and identation of sections etc.