# Why does my table of contents not apply leftskip?

Tags: table-of-contents, leftmargin

I want to use `\leftskip` in my document to achieve a specific layout effect.

Note I'm using `titlesec` to format headings separately (I don't want `leftskip` on these).

But how can I get the `\tableofcontents` to apply `\leftskip`?

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec,blindtext}

\leftskip=6cm

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\leftskip` is a tx primiive that should never be set directly (you mess up any latex lists) as latx needs `\hsize`, \@totallftmargin`, `\leftmargin`, `\linewidh` to have compatible values.  th table of conens in particular is (usually) a lis and sets is own indent, thre are several packags that hlp wih toc formatting you could specify a large left margin using on of those article section toc lins for example set with l@section defind in article.cls that resets leftskip (along wih other things)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks, I didn't realise `\leftskip` was like this. I just found an answer you posted (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/183572/266909) which lead me to the discover the `changepage` package as a way to achieve indented paragraphs.